# Using css animation to make a div element move to each corner of the page

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I would like to know how to use css animation to make a circle div element go to each corner of the page. I have attempted to do this to no avail.

Quite a basic question, but It will help me to understand.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>CSS 201</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Pacifico&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
  .box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 10px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    animation: myAnimation 4s infinite alternate,myAnimation2 4s infinite alternate;
  }
  @keyframes myAnimation {
    0% { top: 0; left: 0; }
    30% { top: 3000px; }
    68%, 72% { left: 50px; }
    100% { top: 3000px; left: 90%; }
  }

  @keyframes myAnimation2{
    0% { bottom: 0; right: 0; }
    30% { top: 3000px; }
    68%, 72% { left: 50px; }
    100% { top: 3000px; left: 90%; }
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier idea using background with no complex keyframes:

```css
.box {
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side,black 97%,transparent) 
    top left/100px 100px /* simply adjust the values here to control the size of the circle */
    no-repeat;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  animation: move 4s infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  25% { background-position: bottom left  }
  50% { background-position: bottom right }
  75% { background-position: top    right }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

CSS Changes

```css
.box {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        border: 10px solid black;
        background-color: black;
        border-radius: 50%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;

        animation: myAnimation 4s infinite;

    }
    @keyframes myAnimation {
        5% { top: 0; left: 0; }
        25% { top: 200px; left: 0px; }
        50% { top: 200px; left: calc(100% - 320px); }
        75% { top: 0px; left: calc(100% - 320px); }
        100% { top: 0px; left: 0; }
    }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: This is perfect if u dont want to use transform: translate(x,y). Thankyou :)

Answer (score 3):

In my solution, I used rule `transform: translate() translateY()` to *prevent* an animated object from creating an **overflow**.

In this solution, the second `@keyframes` with the name `myAnimation2` was removed, since there was no point in this code.

Also, I reduced the size of the animated element for a better visual perception of the animation in my example.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 10px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    animation: myAnimation 4s infinite;
}

@keyframes myAnimation {
    0% {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        transform: translate(0) translateY(0);
    }
    25% {
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
        transform: translateX(0) translateY(-100%);
    }
    50% {
        top: 100%;
        left: 100%;
        transform: translateX(-100%) translateY(-100%);
    }
    75% {
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        transform: translateX(-100%) translateY(0);
    }
    100% {
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        transform: translateX(0) translateY(0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using SMIL SVG
In my opinion, SMIL is a powerful and flexible animation platform that is easily customizable and does not require, like CSS animation, recalculation of timings when the application logic changes.

The flexibility of smil lies in the fact that it is enough to change the logical chains that determine the sequence of animations and this will make it possible to completely rebuild the application without spending significant effort in recalculating timings.

*#1. Solution of the example from the question one ball moves to the corners of the page*

Animation starts after click

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="100vw"     height="95vh" viewBox="0 0 400 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  
<defs>
<radialGradient id="gradB" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="blue" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,192)" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,127)" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,64)" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient>
</defs>  
<rect x="10" y="10" width="380" height="380" rx="25"  fill="green" stroke="#9D8500" stroke-width="15"/>  
<circle cx="30" cy="30" r="3%" fill="url(#gradB)" >
  <animateTransform
    attributeName="transform"
    type="translate"
    begin="svg1.click"
    dur="9s"
    restart="whenNotActive"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
    fill="freeze"
    values="
       0,0;
       340,0;
       340,340;
       0,340;
       0,0;
       0,0" />
</circle>

</svg>
```

*# 2. Added pauses when the ball arrives at the corners*

Pauses are implemented by repeating values in the `values` attribute

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="100vw"     height="95vh" viewBox="0 0 400 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  
<defs>
<radialGradient id="gradB" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="blue" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,192)" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,127)" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,64)" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient>
</defs>  
<rect x="10" y="10" width="380" height="380" rx="25"  fill="green" stroke="#9D8500" stroke-width="15"/>  
<circle cx="30" cy="30" r="3%" fill="url(#gradB)" >
  <animateTransform
    attributeName="transform"
    type="translate"
    begin="svg1.click"
    dur="9s"
    restart="whenNotActive"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
    fill="freeze"
    values="
       0,0;
       340,0;
       340,0;
       340,340;
       340,340;
       0,340;
       0,340;
       0,0;
       0,0" />
</circle>

</svg>
```

*#3. Animation of two balls*

The start of the second animation (red ball) is controlled by a logical chain

`begin="anBlue.begin+3s"`

In words, we can say that the animation of the red ball will start 3s after the start of the animation of the blue ball

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="100vw"     height="95vh" viewBox="0 0 400 400" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  
<defs>
<radialGradient id="gradB" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="blue" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,192)" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,127)" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,64)" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient> 
 <radialGradient id="gradR" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="red" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(192,0,0)" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(127,0,0)" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(64,0,0)" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient>
</defs>  
<rect x="10" y="10" width="380" height="380" rx="25"  fill="green" stroke="#9D8500" stroke-width="15"/>  
   <!-- Red ball -->

<circle cx="30" cy="30" r="3%" fill="url(#gradR)" >
   <!-- Red ball animation  -->
 <animateTransform id="anRed"
    attributeName="transform"
    type="translate"
    begin="anBlue.begin+3s"
    dur="9s"
    restart="whenNotActive"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
    fill="freeze"
    values="
       0,0;
       340,0;
       340,0;
       340,340;
       340,340;
       0,340;
       0,340;
       0,0;
       0,0" />
</circle> 
  <!-- Blue ball -->
<circle cx="30" cy="30" r="3%" fill="url(#gradB)" >
     <!-- Blue ball animation -->
  <animateTransform id="anBlue"
    attributeName="transform"
    type="translate"
    begin="svg1.click"
    dur="9s"
    restart="whenNotActive"
    repeatCount="indefinite"
    fill="freeze"
    values="
       0,0;
       340,0;
       340,0;
       340,340;
       340,340;
       0,340;
       0,340;
       0,0;
       0,0" />
</circle> 
</svg>
```

**[BONUS]**

*#4. Option with a chaotic rebound of balls from the sides of the box*

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="100vh" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
<defs>
 <radialGradient id="gradB" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="blue" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,192)" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,127)" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,64)" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient>

 <radialGradient id="gradR" cx="20%" cy="20%" r="100%" fx="30%" fy="30%">
   <stop stop-color="white" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="red" offset="25%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(192,0,0)" offset="50%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(127,0,0)" offset="70%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(64,0,0)" offset="85%"/>
   <stop stop-color="rgb(0,0,0)" offset="100%"/>
 </radialGradient>
 </defs>
<rect width="100%" height="100%" rx="25"  fill="green" stroke="#9D8500" stroke-width="15"/>
<circle cx="50%" cy="20%" r="3%" fill="url(#gradB)" >
 <animate attributeName="cx" dur="3" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 <animate attributeName="cy" dur="2.8" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
</circle>
<circle cx="30%" cy="70%" r="3%" fill="url(#gradR)" >
 <animate attributeName="cx" dur="2.7" values="97%;3%;97%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 <animate attributeName="cy" dur="3.1" values="3%;97%;3%"  
   repeatCount="indefinite" />
</circle>
</svg>
```